# Where did the song "Yume ni Katachi wa nai keredo" come from in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece, music

The song 夢に形はないけれど ("Yume ni Katachi wa nai keredo") is one of my favorite songs in *One Piece*, but I haven't heard or seen the song in my copy of *One Piece* (I *legally* downloaded *One Piece* in Chinese subtitles and all they do is add subtitles and change nothing else), it's not there.

Is there a reason why it's not there or is it just not in the show to begin with?

Comment: please indicate what you mean by your copy like it's language, whether it;s subbed or dubbed and who was the distributor as Naruto has different opening for the first season depending on who released it (Funimation, 4Kids)

Comment: @Memor-X i have corrected the question because the video on you tube was an edited video that just happen to start at 505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the song is **not** an official *One Piece* song.

It's a parody song of 歌に形はないけれど (*Uta ni Katachi wa Nai keredo*) by doriko (Vocaloid producer) with its lyric changed.

The original song: [NicoNicoDouga](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm2085047) (posted in 2008, the official video posted by doriko himself)

The parody song: [NicoNicoDouga](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm12005006) (first posted in 2010, the original/oldest video with Hatsune Miku as the vocal)